# Hide all buttons if user not logged in

Tags: php, html

I need to Hide  **'Section1'** div and **Log out** button, if user not logged in. in here, checking if user logged in. if it's true, then displaying the user's name in the menu section. if it's not, it will showing 'login or register' buttons.

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/62c1d859ff.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Header Section -->

    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="icon" id="icon">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <div class="username">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <h3 class="name">
                <?php echo isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ? 
                $_SESSION['user_name'] : 
                '<span class="login_register"><a href="signin.php">Login</a> or <a href="register.php">Register</a><span/>';
                
                ?>
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="section1">
            <li><a href="profile.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>Your Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="settings.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>Help</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa-regular fa-message"></i>Send Feedback</a></li>
        </div>
        
        <form action="logout.php" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" class="logout"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>Logout</button>
        </form>
    </div>


    

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried different methods, but i didn' get what i expected..

Comment: how do you know if the user is logged in/out?

Comment: Hiding buttons is insufficient for people who should not have access to specific content. Hiding will as the word indicates just hide the button. That means, that the button is still there and clickable through the dev tools. The only correct solution is, that the button will not be included in the document in the first place.

Comment: This must be done by the backend, not JavaScript/css which would allow the user to override the hiding using devtools. Could you remove those tags and add Wordpress tag? (I’m guessing you are using Wordpress).

Comment: @AHaworth What makes you say wordpress? I don't see anything wordpress-y about this code. But yes of course you're right that the PHP code should check the user's status in the Session, and then either echo the button, or cause it to be skipped. And obviously those pages which the buttons link to, should have their own status checks at the start of their scripts in case anyone goes to them directly. Frankly it seems the OP is not yet in a sufficiently experienced position to be reliably writing authentication software...I never understand why beginners attempt this instead of using modules.

Comment: @ADyson you are of course right about WP, it was a guess and looking more closely likely to be wrong so apologies to the OP.

Comment: @ADyson, _OP is not yet in a sufficiently experienced position to be reliably writing authentication software_ citation needed.

Comment: @PassionateSE The citation is the question. Appears not to realise that checking the session value with an `if` statement would do the job. That is a very simple piece of code.

Comment: @ADyson, checking and echoing a styled button with either bootstrap or materialize would work.

Comment: @PassionateSE I can’t see how anything just on the front end would be sufficient. What am I missing?

Comment: @PassionateSE I know. You don't need to tell me that. But there's more to security than just hiding buttons, as was mentioned at the top of the thread.

Comment: @ADyson, if OP would have used a different framework such as ASP then checking if the user is logged in from the code files and then returning the correct view would be very much easier. But OP did say he tried different methods, maybe he didn't try ASP

Comment: @PassionateSE ??? Why would they suddenly switch to an entirely different language and framework? Not sure how that's relevant. Checking logged-in status in PHP is trivial. _If_ they have actually got their login functionality set up properly, then it should just be a case of checking the existence of a Session variable, e.g. `if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))` or something like that. But if the OP doesn't realise this, it suggests either they haven't actually got such functionality yet, or have no idea how their own authentication system actually works, which is a bit worrying.

Comment: @PassionateSE It seems they have indeeed tried with `<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ? $_SESSION['user_name'] : '<span class="login_register"><a href="signin.php">Login</a> or <a href="register.php">Register</a><span/>';`, although they didn't actually indicate properly if it had worked or not, or what problem occurred. Possibly it's just the wrong session variable name, or possibly the variable isn't set properly, or possibly they somehow don't understand they can use the exact same logic to hide the sesssion1 block. It's not very clear - the question is badly worded and vague.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I block users before entering the page if they are not logged in,

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
{
   header("Location: /login.php?auth=0");
}

?>
```

and in login page,

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
{
   header("Location: /dashboard.php");
}

if(isset($_GET['auth']) && $_GET['auth'] == 0)
{
   echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>You must login first!</div>";
}

?>
```

With this solution, I don't have to modify the HTML content, but blocking them before entering the page. So they need to login first to see their profile or their information.

Comment: it's a little drastic to block a user from entering a page unless he has logged on. On a normal site, you also have unrestricted content. It might work for you but is not an economic and user-friendly solution

Comment: @tacoshy there will also be some pages which are completely off limits to unauthenticated users, or to users without the correct role. That is also very common

Comment: @ADyson but we talk about a page that should be public accessible while just "hiding" certain buttons.

Comment: @tacoshy Sure. But in your comment you appeared to be generalising as if this rule should apply to all pages.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my answer. That is what I usually do in hiding or showing contents to public. The content of menu is also for users who are logged in so that's why my answer is like that. Maybe he also need to limit the contents to be shown in public and add something like, "Login to view information", etc. if the information is "unrestricted" as you say

Comment: @NagonusLrak No need to be sorry. It possibly doesn't suit this particular use case, where the OP wants to just hide certain buttons when the user is logged out, and leave the rest available (you can imagine, it might be the home page of the site perhaps). But what you've shown is what the OP would need to do on the pages which those hidden buttons normally link to, in order to prevent unauthorised direct access.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir @ADyson for your reply. I am now clarified and educated regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To hide these sections, you can simply test the session value, in a similar way to how your code already decides whether to show the username, or show the login button instead:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_name']) {
?>
  <div class="section1">
      <li><a href="profile.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>Your Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="settings.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>Help</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa-regular fa-message"></i>Send Feedback</a></li>
  </div>
        
  <form action="logout.php" method="POST">
      <button type="submit" class="logout"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>Logout</button>
  </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

---

N.B. It's unclear if you realise this or not, but simply hiding these links will not prevent access to the pages that they link to. You will need to ensure that each of these pages has code at the start of it to check the user's login status before displaying the content, and redirect them back to the login page if there is no valid username in the Session. This will prevent anyone from going to those pages directly via the URL, without using the links in your menu.